# Backbone.js nested view not rendering data

Tags: backbone.js, backbone-views

I'm trying to learn nested views with Backbone.js and have run into a problem. No errors are thrown however, it does not display any output or data. Any help would be much appreciated. V/R Chris

link to jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/cpeele00/PcmMW/8/

```
var User = Backbone.Model.extend({});

var Users = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: User
});

var UserItemView = Backbone.View.extend({
    tagName: 'li',
    template: _.template($('#user-list-template').html()),
    render: function() {
        this.$el.html(this.model.toJSON());
        return this;
    }
});

var UserListView = Backbone.View.extend({

    render: function() {
        this.$el.empty();
        var self = this;
        this.collection.each(function(model) {
            self.renderItem(model);
        });
    },

    renderItem: function(item) {
        var itemView = new UserItemView({
            model: item
        });

        this.$el.append(itemView.render().el);
    }

});

var user1 = new User();
user1.set({
    firstname: 'momo',
    lastname: 'peele'
});

var user2 = new User();
user2.set({
    firstname: 'bobo',
    lastname: 'peele'
});

var users = new Users([user1, user2]);

var listView = new UserListView({
    collection: users
});
listView.render();
```

Here's the html and template markup

```
<div id="user-list">
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Users</legend>
    <ul></uL>
  </fieldset>
</div>

<script id="user-list-template" type="text/template">
    <%= firstname %> 
    <%= lastname %> 
</script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There seem to be two problems:

First, typo in `UserItemView`: you're not using the template, just appending JSON.  Instead of

```
this.$el.html(this.model.toJSON());`
```

it should be

```
this.$el.html(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));
```

Second, the `UserListView` isn't attached to the DOM anywhere, so when it gets "rendered", it doesn't appear.  I added

```
el: $("#user-list ul")
```

to the view, so that rendering appends the sub-view items to an element that's actually in the DOM.

[Forked Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HBdmh/1/)

<sub>**PS,** Firebug is your friend.</sub>

Comment: Thanks!! yeah, I use Chrome debugger for the apps I write but it didn't occur to me to actually use that with jsFiddle. Thanks again and take care!